# DolphinDB: error occurs running ploop statement

Tags: sql, dolphindb

When I running the following script in dolphindb, error occurs in the last line:

```py
sym = `C`MS`MS`MS`IBM`IBM`C`C`C$symbol
price= 49.6 29.46 29.52 30.02 174.97 175.23 50.76 50.32 51.29
qty = 2200 1900 2100 3200 6800 5400 1300 2500 8800
timestamp = [09:34:07,09:36:42,09:36:51,09:36:59,09:32:47,09:35:26,09:34:16,09:34:26,09:38:12]
t0 = table(timestamp, sym, qty, price);

t1 = select  sum((qty))  as qty from t0  group by  minute(timestamp) as ts,sym,price;
t2 = select  log((qty))  as qty from t0  group by  minute(timestamp) as ts ,sym,price;

name = `ts`q
typeString = `MINUTE`INT
tResult=table(1:0,name,typeString)
share tResult as shareT

ploop(myFunc,([t1,shareT],[t2, shareT]))
```

What did I understand wrong about the ploop statement?

[image]

Comment: what's the error message ? add it to your question

Answer (score 0):

You may use partial application to fix the first few parameters. In this case, the last line of your code can be revised to

```
ploop(myFunc{,shareT},[t1,t2])
```

More information on the partial application can be found from dolphindb's [tutorial](https://www.dolphindb.com/help/Functionalprogramming/PartialApplication.html).